# Connect a table to many to many table

Tags: laravel, eloquent, many-to-many, one-to-many, laravel-5.7

I have a many to many table from goods and companies and i want to connect it with a one to many table
company_good

```
+----------------+------------+
|    company_ID    | good_ID |
+----------------+------------+
| 1              |       1    |
| 2              |       1    |
| 2              |       2    |
+----------------+------------+
```

sales

```
+----------+----------------+--------------+----------+
|    id    |      date      |  company_id  |  good_id |
+----------+----------------+--------------+----------+
| 1        |  2019-02-01    |      1       |     1    |
| 2        |  2019-02-01    |      2       |     1    |
| 2        |  2019-02-01    |      1       |     1    |
+----------+----------------+--------------+----------+
```

what i want to ask is are there any naming column on sales based on laravel rule? what i know is when a table `posts` want to connect it to table `users` the naming on table `post` should be `user_id`. but in this case how do i name it?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Answer (score 0):

First off, you'll definitely want to use Eloquent for this.

The column names can be whatever you want them to be. When you set up a many to many model method you can define the related column names in there

Here's an extract from the Laravel documentation:

> In addition to customizing the name of the joining table, you may also
>   customize the column names of the keys on the table by passing
>   additional arguments to the belongsToMany method. The third argument
>   is the foreign key name of the model on which you are defining the
>   relationship, while the fourth argument is the foreign key name of the
>   model that you are joining to:
>
> return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role', 'role_user', 'user_id',
>   'role_id');

Read more at https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to add an `id` column to `company_good` table and name corresponding model as `CompanyGood` and instead of `company_id` and `good_id` in `sales` table use `company_good_id` column